# Show users connected to voice channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to know is it possible to know if any member is connected to a any voice channel in discord.js v12.2.0. Please let me know if you have any clues on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [VoiceChannel.members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members)

```js
const vc = <message>.guild.channels.cache.get('VC Id')
const members = vc.members //COLLECTION
```

To check if a member is in vc, use [GuildMember.voice](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice)

```js
const vc = <member>.voice.channel //VOICE CHANNEL
//if you want, you can check the vc name, id, etc with vc.name, vc.id, etc
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example for what you said in the comments

```js
//MAKE SURE IT IS ASYNC CALLBACK
await client.guilds.fetch();
const VCs = [];
client.guilds.cache.forEach(async guild => {
await guild.channels.fetch();
let VCs = guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'voice');
VCs.forEach(vc => {
if(vc.members) {
VCs.push(vc)
}
})
})
```

I hope this is what you wanted (`VCs` is an array with all VCs with members)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i wish to use the function on all voice channels and servers

Comment: I don’t understand, you want to see if a specific person is in a vc? You want to see if a vc has any people in it? You want to log all the vcs with people in it?

Comment: yes i want to log all the vcs with people in it

Comment: Use a forEach loop for `client.guilds.cache` where you also do forEach with all the VCs. I will edit my answer to give you an example

Comment: I already exited it. If it helps, please mark it as accepted.